# Detect @ and then add CSS using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

From the backend, I get JSON in the following format: `<p>@username This is awesome.</p>`

I have to detect `@` in a word and then add a class to the entire word or a span so I can modify the word to something like this:

```css
p span {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  }
```

```html
<p><span>@username</span> This is awesome</p>
```

How do I detect using javascript to get this going? Please note that `@` could be anywhere in the paragraph.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text)

Comment: How is the JSON being passed in?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=stackoverflow+javascript+at+mention+regex

Comment: @AndyRay No. It's not. I have made changes to the question.

Comment: @dmikester1 It's on Angular and so using html-bind. The output after parsing is what is shown in the question.

Comment: Interesting problem! Twitter @bombs? Will there ever be an instance where there's an email in the paragraph string? Then you would need to detect the difference between an @bomb and an email

Comment: @MathiasRechtzigel Interesting. Had not thought about an email perspective! Thanks. I found a solution using regex js. Will post an answer if i find something. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This bit of regex will find any word beginning with `@` and wrap it (and the `@`) in a `span` tag.

```js
var json = "{\"text\":\"<p>@username This is awesome.</p>\"}",
  text = JSON.parse(json).text;

text = text.replace(/(@\w+)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
console.log(text);
```

This will not work for email addresses. e.g. `a@b.com` will become `a<span>@b</span>.com`. Do you need a solution that takes this into account?